# create html at run time with ngOptions AngulasJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, javascript-objects

I have a page with a button when the user clicks, it generates an html snippet with 3 inputs and a select. The select is using the angular ngOptions policy, all the code is in the controller's angle the problem is that the select is not being populated with data coming from the API.

Follows the code below the angular controller and the function behind the API data:

```
    function selecionaSituacao(){

        console.log("hiughj");

    $http.get('/configuracao/situacao').success(function(situacaolista){

        $scope.situacoes = situacaolista;
        console.log("funcção selecionaSituacao();");

    },
    function(erro){
        console.log(erro);
        console.log('não foi possível obter o equipamento');
    });
};


var id = 0;
$scope.adicionalinha = function(){




        $http.get('/inicio/'+$routeParams.id).success(
            function(memorando){
                console.log("memorando tamanho "+memorando.tabela.length);
                id += memorando.tabela.length;
            },
            function(erro){
                console.log('não foi possível obter o tamanho do array')
            });




$("#btn-adiciona").on('click', function(event){


    event.preventDefault();



    var tdConteudo = '<td><input type="text" id="t'+id+'" placeholder="Tombo" required ng-model="memorando.tabela.tombo"></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" id="d'+id+'" placeholder="Descrição" required ng-model="memorando.tabela.descricao"></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" id="l'+id+'" placeholder="Local" required ng-model="memorando.tabela.local"></td>'+
                    '<td><select id="s'+id+'" ng-model="memorando.tabela.situacao" ng-options="situ.situacao for situ in situacoes">'+
                            '<option value="">--Escolha uma situação--</option>'+
                        '</select></td>'+
                    '<td><a id="'+id+'" class="remove-item" href=""><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>';


                    ++id;


    $('<tr>').append(tdConteudo).appendTo('#tabela-body');  

    selecionaSituacao();            

    });


};
```

Thank you all.
:)

Comment: This isn't going to work the way you want.  You can't use JQuery to append arbitrary HTML into the DOM and expect Angular to parse it.

Comment: without seeing the HTML, it's not easy to tell you the "Angular" way to do this, but it looks like you have an array of data, consider using `ng-repeat` instead of using JQuery to iterate through the array.